# router works on localhost but not in production in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.js framework and the router seems to work in local but not in production

```
router.route(`/server/template/:id`)
  .delete(test.delete)
  .get(temp.get);


router.route(`/server/template`)
  .post(test.post)
  .get(test.get);
```

I get the below error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Comment: Which one fails? Does the template defined by `id` really exist (different database?). Is that document your defined 404 answer? How about ip bindings? Is any other service running in the production environment, that may use the same port? The node code itself does not really distinguish between debug and production, so the error is either in machine configuration or some part of the code, you don't sjow

Comment: "/server/template/:id" is able to take the incoming calls but "/server/template" fails

Comment: Well, your route is defined as `/server/templates` so if you call `/server/template` (note the missing s in the end) there is no valid route, because `/server/template/{id}` requires an id. So, to be honest, I doubt requesting  `/server/template` works on local

Comment: oops my bad thats a typo. It's /server/template. I will update my question.

Comment: If that's the case, the error is not in the code you are showing us

Answer (score -2):

You need to use Apache Web-server to simulate an HTML server on your own machine or on the internet, or apache friends or XAMPP, or IIS.

Comment: In my case Node app is not serving a html page. It just acts like a REST application to create/update/get details from database.

Comment: Any idea what node and express.js is? Obviously not